# "(" unexpected Python calling javascript

Tags: javascript, python

I have a project on my RaspPI where I need to call a .js from python.
That is the line where i call it:

```
cmd = "/home/pi/temperature/TurnOn.js"
  subprocess.call(cmd, shell = True)
```

The error message:      Syntax error: "(" unexpected

I already tried os.system()

I am using this git in the .js:   https://github.com/jhfoo/hs100-api
Is this caused by python or JavaScript and how can I fix it?

Greetings

Comment: Seems like your javascript code is interpreted by the shell. What happens if you call `/home/pi/temperature/TurnOn.js` from the shell?

Comment: When I call it like this:   "Command not found"
When I call "node /home/pi/temperature/TurnOn.js":   "(node:5131) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead."
But the code is being executed and does what it should

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bash syntax error. Your js file is being executed by bash.

You have to specify the interpreter in your command for example:

```py
cmd = "node /home/pi/temperature/TurnOn.js"
  subprocess.call(cmd, shell = False)
```

Comment: Thx that worked, but I am still getting the DeprecationWarning.

Comment: I assume this is a problem of that `TurnOn.js` not the python script as the warning  message you wrote in a comment under your question is a node warning.